# Linq to SQL different result set depend on conditions

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

In my stored procedure `proc1`:

```
IF (condition1)
    BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM table1
    END;
ELSE IF (condition2)
    BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM table2
    END;
```

but in the `designer.cs`, I only see a `proc1Result` class with only 14 properties that resemble 14 columns in `table1`. Table2's 23 columns cannot be found as properties or fields. therefore when `condition2` is met,

```
ISingleResult<proc1Result> results = datacontext1.proc1(parameter);
foreach (proc1Result item in results){
    resultList.Add(
        new model2{
            // no property to set here
        }
    );
}
```

What can I do to add `Table2`'s columns to the `proc1Result` class?

Comment: I'd suggest rethinking a design where a stored procedure can return completely different result sets.  Maybe this logic can be moved out of the DB?  Otherwise you have to return a combination of the data for both.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a result that has columns from both tables.
Something like this (but if they have the same "name" for some columns you will have to list out all the columns to avoid duplicates / create aliases):

```sql
IF (condition1)
    BEGIN
        SELECT t1.*,t2.* 
        FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
        -- return no results from t2, fieldname can never be null
        WHERE t2.fieldname != t2.fieldname 
    END;
ELSE IF (condition2)
    BEGIN
        SELECT t1.*,t2.* 
        FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
        -- return no results from t1, fieldname can never be null.
        WHERE t1.fieldname != t1.fieldname 
    END;
```

Comment: in my original design, under some conditions, the `SELECT` statement does not have a `WHERE` clause. How can I add something like `WHERE table_name is "table1"`?

Comment: @DylanChensky - you can't.

Comment: @DylanChensky - I expect you have not tried the code in my answer and don't understand it.  Please try it, understand it and then see why your question did not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

`proc1Result` will hold the properties from both the models, so when first condition executed properties of second will be ignored and vice versa.

```
Class proc1Result {

    //properties for table1

    //properties for table2

    }

 Class model1{

    //properties for table1

    } 

Class model2 {

    //properties for table2

    }


    ISingleResult<proc1Result> results = datacontext1.proc1(parameter);
    foreach (proc1Result item in results){
        resultList.Add(
            new model2{
                item.propertyname //which is there in both model2 and proc1result

            }
        );
    }
```